# How to swipe an element using hammer.js in Backbone View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, hammer.js

I'm pretty new to both backbone and hammer, but it took me a long time and I still didn't achieve my goal, so if someone could help, I'd be really thankful!
I want to have this functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/uZjCB/7/

but using it in a backbone view.
This is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Using backbone</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">        
</head>
<style>
body {
overflow:hidden;
height: 100%;
}
.colorContainer {
position: relative;
padding:0 100px;
width: 40%;
border: 1px solid;
margin-top: 25px;
}
.color{
position: relative;
left: 100px;
width:50px;
height:50px;
cursor:pointer;
}
#red .color {
background: red;
}
</style>
<body>          
<script type="text/template" id="template">
<div id="red" class="colorContainer">
<div class="color redColor"></div>
</div>
</script>

<div id="container"></div>

<script src="js/jquery1.9.js"></script>
<script src="js/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="js/backbone.js"></script>      
<script src="js/jquery.hammer.js"></script> 
<script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
View = Backbone.View.extend({ 
initialize: function(){ 
    this.render();
}, 

render: function() {
    var template = _.template($("#template").html(), {} );
    this.$el.html( template );
    this.$el.hammer();
},

events: {
    "swipe" : "swipeIt"
},

swipeIt: function(e){
    if (e.direction == 'right') {
         console.log("You swiped right");
    }
    else if (e.direction == 'left') {
        console.log("You swiped left");
    }
}

});

var view = new View({ el: $("#container") });
```

Unfortunately when I swipe the square nothing is displayed in the console. Anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: Could you add a `console.log('swiped') just inside the swipeIt function to confirm it's being fired at all?  (eg: not inside the if/else)

Comment: Tried it and it works. The entered string is displayed in the console.

Comment: In that case, I'd say it's simply that the event object doesn't have the properties you're searching for (or it does, but it has an unexpected value).  Do a `console.log(e)` and see if 'direction' is a property on it.  I think in an earlier version, the direction info might have been stored in `e.gesture.direction`, but you should be able to see for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Twicetimes this is done by calling e.gesture.direction, instead of just e.direction. Example:

```
swipeIt: function(e){
if (e.gesture.direction == 'right') {
     console.log("You swiped right");
}
else if (e.gesture.direction == 'left') {
    console.log("You swiped left");
}
}
```