# How to get Hammer JS to work with Backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, hammer.js, backbone-events

I know this has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083933/hammer-js-not-working-with-backbone), [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039285/using-backbone-js-with-hammer-js), and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449649/how-to-swipe-an-element-using-hammer-js-in-backbone-view).

As I struggled for hours finding out the right combination, based on those answers, I thought I would sum it up here, so WE all can find it more clearly and easily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, it is possible to get Hammer to work flawlessly with Backbone.

To reach this goal, you just need to follow this list :

1. Include the [hammer.js dependency](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/master/hammer.min.js) into your project.
2. Include [Hammer's jQuery plugin](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hammerjs/jquery.hammer.js/master/jquery.hammer.js) into your project
3. Create a Hammer Manager instance so you can listen for Hammer events. You should initiate the instance on the same element you are triggering the touch events, or an enclosing one (typically, [your view element](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el)). 
   Thus something like this should be present at the end of your View's `render()` function :

   ```
   this.$el.hammer(); // Instantiates Hammer Manager
   ```
4. Listen for an event, as you normally would for any javascript/jQuery event :

   `events : { 
     "pan #some_selector": "some_handler",
   }`
5. In your event handler, you can access the event's properties within the `gesture` attribute, not directly as written in Hammer's documentation, as follows :

   `function some_handler : function(event) {
      console.log(event.gesture.deltaX);
   },`

This should get Hammer to work flawlessly with your Backbone application.
I hope this helps! :)

Comment: How does #4 listen for events? This is just a literal object? How do you use it?

Comment: Hmmm, you need to learn how [Backbone views](http://backbonejs.org/#View) work, and how to declare [event maps](http://backbonejs.org/#View-events) within your views I think. 

As far as I am concerned, this is the best resource I found to [learn BackboneJS](https://bardevblog.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/understanding-backbone-js-simple-example/). I hope this helps

Comment: I wasn’t aware that #4 specifically was BackboneJS as none of the other parts were.

Comment: They do actually :) 
3. and 5. and also Backbone related.

Comment: Okay. I found them very hammerjs and jquery related.

Answer (score 2):

Struggled a bit getting this going using Require, Backbone, and Hammer. Here's what worked for me.

**Require Config:**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "/bower_components/jquery/jquery",
        "underscore": "/bower_components/underscore/underscore",
        "backbone": "/bower_components/backbone/backbone",
        "hammerjs": "/bower_components/hammerjs/hammer",
        "jquery-hammerjs": "/bower_components/jquery-hammerjs/jquery.hammer"
    },

    shim: {
        "backbone": {
            deps: [ "jquery-hammerjs", "underscore" ],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },
        "underscore": {
            exports: "_"
        }
    }
});
```

**View File**

```
define( "myview", [ "backbone" ], function( Backbone ) {
    "use strict";

    return Backbone.View.extend( {
        el: ".my-el",

        events: {
            "tap .child-of-my-el": "handleTap"
        },

        initialize: function() {
            this.$el.hammer( { domEvents: true } );
        }
    } );
} );
```

Note the **domEvents** option. Event delegation won't work with this. [Hammer docs states that this may slow things down a bit](http://hammerjs.github.io/api/#domevents-false) so YMMV.